# Weird for loop behavior with duplicate array elements

Tags: javascript, arrays, for-loop

I wanted make `[1,2,3,4,5].duplicated()` works but when I wrote:

```
Array.prototype.duplicator = function (){
    var a = [];
    for(var i=0;i<10;i+=2){
    a[i]=this[i];
    a[i+1]=this[i];
}
return a;
};
 [1,2,3,4,5].duplicator();
```

it returns `[1, 1, 3, 3, 5, 5, undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined]` instead of `[1,1,2,2,3,3,4,4,5,5]`. Can anyone tell me why it does not work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could just `map` and flatten for a more functional approach:

```
Array.prototype.duplicate = function() {
  return [].concat.apply([], this.map(function(v) {
    return [v,v];
  }));
};

console.log([1,2,3].duplicate()); //=> [1,1,2,2,3,3]
```

Answer (score 5):

```
Array.prototype.duplicator=function()
{
    return  this.concat(this)
}

alert([1,2,3,4,5].duplicator());
```

Comment: This is the best one.

Comment: This isn't quite what the OP is asking for. Your solution will result in:

`[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5]`

Rather than what they want:

`[1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 4, 4, 5, 5]`

I presume the person asking this question is trying to solve a question from [this link](http://darcyclarke.me/development/front-end-job-interview-questions/). In which case your solution Olga is correct!

Answer (score 1):

The simplest answer should be:

```
Array.prototype.duplicator=function () {
    return this.concat(this).sort();
}

console.log([1,2,3,4,5].duplicator());//[1,1,2,2,3,3,4,4,5,5]
```

Answer (score 0):

Because you're adding 2 at each iteration, thus stepping beyond the array boundaries. Try this instead:

```
for (var i=0; i<this.length; i++) {
    a.push(this[i]);
    a.push(this[i]);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You would want to place each value in `i*2` and `i*2+1` instead of `i` and `i+1`, and loop one step at a time:

```
Array.prototype.duplicator = function (){
  var a = [];
  for(var i = 0; i < this.length; i++){
    a[i*2] = this[i];
    a[i*2+1] = this[i];
  }
  return a;
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a fix:

```
Array.prototype.duplicator = function() {
  var dup = [];
  for (var i = 0; i < this.length; i++) {
    dup[2 * i] = dup[2 * i + 1] = this[i];
  }
  return dup;
};

console.log([1,2,3,4,5].duplicator());
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Array.prototype.duplicator = function () {
    var a = [], k = 0;
    for(var i=0;i<this.length;i++) {
       a[k]=this[i];
       k++;
       a[k]=this[i];
       k++;
    }
    return a;
};
```

Comment: The question was "Can anyone tell me why it does not work?", so please add some explanation.

Comment: Simple exaplianation that your code contain bug. At secound iteration your i===2 so this[i] === 3

Comment: You should edit the question rather than posting a comment. Stack Overflow's format is Q&A, not discussion thread.

Comment: How about to open any programming book, before teach other people how to use Stack Overflow?

Comment: @AdiInbar - editing the code in the question is a bad idea. It could hide the cause of the problem. There's nothing wrong with posting an answer that shows the correct code - as long as it includes an explanation.

Comment: @ChrisF Heh...I mistyped that, it should read "edit the **answer**"--i.e. include the explanation in the answer itself rather than conversationally in comments.

Comment: @Nikita How about learning from constructive criticism rather than getting defensive? If that's too much to ask, how about paying attention before making misplaced snide comments? I'm not the poster of the question, I'm a reviewer who encountered your post in the Low Quality Posts review queue. Another reviewer voted to delete, but I voted against deletion because I felt it would be more constructive to provide you feedback and an opportunity to improve your answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
duplicator = val => val.concat(val);
```

Answer (score 0):

This works for me following the case in https://github.com/h5bp/Front-end-Developer-Interview-Questions/blob/master/src/questions/javascript-questions.md, where the desired result is [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5]. Hope it works for you!

```
const duplicate = (...nums) => [].concat(...nums, ...nums);

console.log(duplicate([1, 2, 3, 4, 5]));
```